# Ignoring first five columns in grep regex

Tags: regex, grep

I am having a csv file and I want to look for the lines that contains "ABC","12" and "45" say. But I dont want to check in first five columns for "ABC" . So I wrote this regex :

```
(.*?,)(.*?,)(.*?,)(.*?,)(.*?,).*,ABC,.*,12,.*,45,.*
```

But when I do

```
grep '(.*?,)(.*?,)(.*?,)(.*?,)(.*?,).*,ABC,.*,12,.*,45,.*' in.csv| wc -l
```

I am getting zero rows.

But if I dont ignore first five columns and do

```
grep '.*,ABC,.*,12,.*,45,.*' in.csv| wc -l
```

Then I am getting 4962 rows.

But in actual they are less rows in csv that satisfy this. So what am missing in first regex.

Input :

```
306702,00848719009996,NULL,B,ABC,199.00,189.05,311,XYZ,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,9SIA3G62HJ3818,12,45
```

Should not match

```
306702,00848719009996,NULL,B,ABC,199.00,189.05,311,ABC,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,9SIA3G62HJ3818,12,45
```

Should match

Comment: try `grep -P  '^(.*?,)(.*?,)(.*?,)(.*?,)(.*?,).*(?<=,)ABC(?=,).*,12(?=,).*,45,.*' in.csv| wc -l `

Comment: @AvinashRaj Still zero rows

Comment: post a sample input..

Comment: try `grep -P '^(.*?,)(.*?,)(.*?,)(.*?,)(.*?,).*(?<=,)ABC(?=,).*,12(?=,).*,45(?=,|$).*' in.csv| wc -l`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Its fine when I try on sublime etc. Is some special charcaters need to be escaped for grep here ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Not able to figure out problem here.

Comment: @AvinashRaj  Hey are you able to get problem ?

Answer (score -1):

using tail and pipe the output to grep can do,
    `tail -n +5 in.csv|grep 'ABC'|grep '12'|grep '45'` 
Here +5 for all lines after 5

if order of matches is important you can try:
   `tail -n +5 in.csv|grep -E 'ABC.*12.*45'`

if you would like to match any one of matches grep OR can do the magic
   `grep 'ABC\|12\|45'`

Comment: The OP is trying to discard certain columns, but the `tail` command will discard certain *lines.*

Answer (score -1):

Grep skipping first and second column

```
grep "xxx" file.log | awk '{$1="";$2="";print}'
```

Comment: The `grep` command will search the file *including* the columns that were supposed to be excluded. The `awk` command will not operate on comma-separated records but on whitespace-separated records, so this will not do anything like what the OP asked for.